# File handling in GWT(at server side)

Tags: gwt

I have some doubt regarding gwt file handling.

1. How to do file handling in gwt(at server side). How to create simple file. I mean which class is particularly used for CREATING and HANDLING it ??
2. Where is the file created. Is it under server package or somewhere else ??
3. How to resolve serialization and serialization problem. ??

Answer (score 2):

GWT is a client-side technology. It's server-agnostic (and can also be used client-only, e.g. mobile apps, Chrome apps, browser extensions). GWT-RPC and RequestFactory use Java servlets by default (nothing precludes implementing RequestFactory in other languages/technologies) but have otherwise no requirement or limitations.

So, server-side, it's all just Java in most of the cases, and depends on your deployment target (e.g. AppEngine restricts what you can do, servlet containers can also have security policies in place, and you're of course dependent on authorizations at the filesystem level)

Answer (score 0):

Since GWT is a pure client-side technology you have all possible options like plain Servlets for example. You are not limited in any way in picking the upload approach.

However, there is a number of open source projects, which make possible to use nice features like progress bars and multiple file uploads. And those come integrated with some GWT widgets as well. Check this project for example http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/

Comment: I checked the link. It tells about how to upload a file.